# ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer mouse driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers

I would like to know where can I find the driver of ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer mouse. I was unable to find it through Google!

Comment: Should "Just Work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer mouse" unpacks to:

- it's a PS/2 mouse, so the standard Linux PS/2 mouse driver will handle it.
- "ImEx" probably refers to Intellimouse/Explorer, which means the mouse protocol includes extensions that support more than 2 buttons and possibly a scroll wheel or two. All these protocol features are autodetected by the Linux PS/2 mouse driver.

The driver is configured by the CONFIG_MOUSE_PS2 kernel source configuration option. If your `/boot/config-<kernel-version-number>` file has a line that says,

```
CONFIG_MOUSE_PS2=y
```

then the driver is built-in to the kernel and should Just Work, as @ivanivan said in the comments.

If the `/boot/config-<kernel-version-number>` instead has a line that says:

```
CONFIG_MOUSE_PS2=m
```

then the driver is built as a loadable module named `psmouse`. It should normally be autodetected, but you can use `sudo modprobe psmouse` if it is not loaded for some reason (e.g. blacklisted by configuration).